# Laravel JWT: Unable to implement JWTSubject

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am new to laravel and I intended to make an authentication to my API calls. So here it goes...

I've followed the step by step [guide](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) on setting up jwt-auth on laravel

After installing it, I changed the version jwt-auth in the `composer.json` and run `composer update`

> ```
> "require": {
>         "php": "^7.2.5",
>         "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
>         "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
>         "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
>         "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
>         "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
>         "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.5.1" //Originally "^1.0"
>     },
> ```

I dont know if this was the reason, but, in my User.php Model, i was not able to implement JWTSubject

Here's the User.php model:

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App;
>
> use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
> use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
> use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
> class User extends Authenticatable implements App\JWTSubject //It says 'undefined type App\App\JWTSubject
> {
>     use Notifiable;
>
>     /**
>      * The attributes that are mass assignable.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $fillable = [
>         'name', 'email', 'password',
>     ];
>
>     /**
>      * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $hidden = [
>         'password', 'remember_token',
>     ];
>
>     /**
>      * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $casts = [
>         'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
>     ];
> }
> ```

**UPDATED: New issue found:**
I decided to proceed to the guide, however, after I created the `AuthController.php`, I noticed that the `attempt`, `logout`, `refresh`, and `factory` methods has errors saying `undefined method`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `implements App\JWTSubject` again it already you have used

So, `implements` it with only `JWTSubject`

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
```

Please check out the [document](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/)

Comment: I thought so, but still when I remove `App\` it gives me the same error.

Comment: do you have this file? https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Contracts/JWTSubject.php

Comment: Yes I have. I even changed the jwt-auth version back to its original version. but still nothing.